# jQuery select elements with value between x and y

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'd like to be able to do that kind of selection:

```
$('input[value between 6 and 11]');
```

Which would give me the 9 and 10.
Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with `.filter()` like this:

```
$("input").filter(function() { 
  return $(this).val() >= 6 && $(this).val() <= 11; 
}).somethingHere();
```

If you need to use this often, you could make it a selector as well:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].between = function(a, b, c) { 
   var args = c[3].split(',');
   var val = parseInt(jQuery(a).val());
   return val >= parseInt(args[0]) && val <= parseInt(args[1]);
};
```

Then you can select by:

```
$("input:between(6, 11)")
```

Just change the `>=` and `<=` if you don't want the range to be inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the filter [function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('input').filter(function(index) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    return !isNaN(value) && value > 6 && value < 11;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know how to use filter()

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.filter()`:

```
$("input").filter(function(){
   var v = parseInt($(this).val());
   return (v > 9 && v < 11)
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know how to use filter()